# ¿Por qué se ven afectados los campos de dos variables del mismo tipo?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas! Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class Persona
{
    // ...
    public string Apellido;
}

public class Program 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Persona A = new Persona(); A.Apellido = "Mendez";
        Persona B = A; // El apellido debe ser Mendez.
        //Pero...
        Console.WriteLine("Apellido de A: " + A.Apellido); // Mendez ahora.
        A.Apellido = "Castillo"; // Si por algún "error" debo cambiarlo.
        Console.WriteLine("Nuevo Apellido de A: " + A.Apellido); // Castillo ahora.
        Console.WriteLine("Apellido de B: " + B.Apellido); // Castillo igual.
    }
}
```

¿Por qué el campo `Apellido` en la variable B se ve afectado por el cambio en la variable A y viceversa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se ve afectado porque lo objetos se asignan por referencia. Cuando asignas de esta forma

```
Persona B = A;
```

la instancia de B es un puntero a la de A, cualquier cambio que realices a cualquiera de las variables afectara a la otra.

Para no tener ese problema debes crear una instancia distintas o crear un clone.

[Cómo: Escribir un constructor Copy (Guía de programación de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/ms173116.aspx)

analiza en el ejemplo como define un constructor para crear una nueva copia a partir de una existente.

Tambien podrias analizar el uso del

[Object.MemberwiseClone (Método)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

podrias crear una copia en otra instancia.

Answer (score 9):

Lo que pasa es que las variables de clase solo mantienen una referencia a la instancia (similar a punteros) así que tienes una sola instancia que puedes acceder a través de dos variables diferentes, es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando la asignas a otra variable no significa que se cree una nueva instancia y se copien los valores de los campos.

Comment: +1 Una imagen vale mas que 1024 palabras :)

Comment: Es el mismo comentario que pensaba agregar!, excelente respuesta!

Comment: Gracias, sabía que algún día mis habilidades en Paint iban a ser útiles.

Answer (score 4):

Porque estas usando la misma instancia de A para B;

```
 Persona A = new Persona(); A.Apellido = "Mendez";
 Persona B = A; // El apellido debe ser Mendez.
```

Al cambiar alguna propiedad en A, los cambios se ven reflejados en B.

Para no tener problemas puedes crear otra instancia de la clase `Persona()` para la variable B:

```
 Persona A = new Persona(); 
 Persona B = new Persona();
```

O crea un clone, puede crear un método para copiar un objeto, este es un ejemplo:

```
Objeto copyObjeto (Objeto objeto){
  Objeto f = new Objeto();
  //Para todas las propiedades de 
  f.set(objeto.get());
  return f;
}
```

Acerca de **[Copy Constructor (Español)](https://javatrench.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/copia-de-objetos-en-java-deep-copy-constructor-de-copia/)**